# Python - sort lists based on their sum

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list that contains lists based on the sum of each inner list.

here's the current snippet I've got

```
vectors = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    vectors.append(generate_vector()) # generate_vector() works, creates a list

for vector in vectors:
    coin_list = findbest(vector) # findbest(vector) outputs a list
    print coin_list, fitness(coin_list) # fitness(coin_list) gives the sum of coin_list
```

I want to sort vectors based on the results of fitness(coin_list) from low to high. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `key` param in sorted function

```
data = [[1,2,3], [14, 7], [5, 6, 1]]
print sorted(data, key=sum)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 1], [14, 7]]
```

If you want to sort inplace

```
data = [[1,2,3], [14, 7], [5, 6, 1]]
data.sort(key=sum)
print data
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 1], [14, 7]]
```

**Edit** Just in case, if you are wondering how to sort in descending order, you can use `reverse` parameter like this

```
data.sort(key=sum, reverse=True)
sorted(data, key=sum, reverse=True)
```

So, in your case

```
vectors = [generate_vector() for i in range(0, 10)]
print sorted([findbest(vector) for vector in vectors], key=sum)
```

Thats it.

Comment: Or, `data.sort(key=sum)` to do it in place.

Comment: The problem is the sum is not actually sum(data), but sum(function(data)). I have gotten stuck at that point.

Comment: Right, findbest is function(data)

Comment: @user2733911 And this doesnt work for you? `print sorted([findbest(vector) for vector in vectors], key=sum)`

Comment: No because I want the vectors array sorted, not the array of findbest(vector). But I realized I had a massive flaw in my ideology of this program, and this problem was eliminated.

Comment: So I solved it by doing sorted([findbest(vector) for vector in vectors], key=sum(findbest(vector)).

Comment: What if there is a tie? Then which element in the list comes first? Is it ordered by index?

Answer (score 3):

```
vectors = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    vectors.append(generate_vector()) # generate_vector() works, creates a list

for vector in vectors:
    coin_list = findbest(vector) # findbest(vector) outputs a list
    print sorted(fitness(coin_list), key=sum)
```